# Wt::Http::Client always end with throw_exception<boost::bad_weak_ptr>()

Tags: c++, boost, wt

I am currently doing modifications to an existing program written in C++11 with Wt and boost. One problem still remains, I always get exception when posting data using the `Wt::Http::Client`.

Here is the current code :

**Communication.h**

```
#ifndef COMMUNICATION_H_
#define COMMUNICATION_H_

#include <Wt/WResource>
#include <Wt/Http/Client>
#include <Wt/Http/Message>

class Communication
{
    public:
        static bool sendData(std::string p_sData);
        static void handleHTTPResponse(boost::system::error_code err, const Wt::Http::Message& response);

    private:
        Communication();
        ~Communication();
};

#endif /* COMMUNICATION_H_ */
```

**Communication.cpp**

```
#include "Communication.h"
#include <Wt/WDateTime>
#include "DemtroysUtilitaires.h"

Communication::Communication()
{

}

Communication::~Communication()
{

}

bool Communication::sendData(std::string p_sData)
{
    Wt::Http::Client requete;
    Wt::Http::Message message;
    bool bResult = false;

    std::cout << "NETWORK >>> " << p_sData << std::endl;

    message.addHeader("Content-type","application/json");
    message.addBodyText(p_sData);
    requete.done().connect(boost::bind(&Communication::handleHTTPResponse,_1,_2));

    if(requete.post("http://someserver.com",message))
    {
        bResult = true;
    }

    return bResult;
}

void Communication::handleHTTPResponse(boost::system::error_code err, const Wt::Http::Message& response)
{
    std::cout << "********************************************************************************" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Communication::handleHttpResponse() status : " << response.status() << std::endl;
    if(err || response.status() != 200)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << err.message() << ", " << response.status() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "********************************************************************************" << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the stack trace :

```
Thread [15] 28055 [core: 3] (Suspended : Signal : SIGABRT:Aborted)  
    __GI_raise() at raise.c:56 0x7ffff5914cc9   
    __GI_abort() at abort.c:89 0x7ffff59180d8   
    __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() at 0x7ffff5f196b5  
    0x7ffff5f17836  
    std::terminate() at 0x7ffff5f17863  
    __cxa_throw() at 0x7ffff5f17aa2 
    throw_exception<boost::bad_weak_ptr>() at throw_exception.hpp:70 0x7ffff767682c 
    boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count() at shared_count.hpp:580 0x7ffff767682c  
    shared_ptr<Wt::Http::Client::Impl>() at shared_ptr.hpp:404 0x7ffff79201b8   
    shared_from_this() at enable_shared_from_this.hpp:49 0x7ffff79201b8 
    Wt::Http::Client::Impl::startTimer() at Client.C:143 0x7ffff79201b8 
    Wt::Http::Client::Impl::handleResolve() at Client.C:173 0x7ffff7925d2d  
    operator() at mem_fn_template.hpp:280 0x7ffff7924afc    
    operator()<boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Wt::Http::Client::Impl, const boost::system::error_code&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::_bi::list2<const boost::system::error_code&, const boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&> > at bind.hpp:392 0x7ffff7924afc   
    operator()<boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > at bind_template.hpp:102 0x7ffff7924afc  
    operator() at bind_handler.hpp:127 0x7ffff7924afc   
    asio_handler_invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Wt::Http::Client::Impl, boost::system::error_code const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Wt::Http::Client::Impl*>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >, boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > at handler_invoke_hook.hpp:69 0x7ffff7924afc  
    invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Wt::Http::Client::Impl, boost::system::error_code const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Wt::Http::Client::Impl*>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >, boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Wt::Http::Client::Impl, boost::system::error_code const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Wt::Http::Client::Impl*>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> > > at handler_invoke_helpers.hpp:37 0x7ffff7924afc 
    boost::asio::detail::resolve_op<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, Wt::Http::Client::Impl, boost::system::error_code const&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<Wt::Http::Client::Impl*>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> > >::do_complete at resolve_op.hpp:112 0x7ffff7924afc 
    complete() at task_io_service_operation.hpp:38 0x7ffff773cfef   
    do_run_one() at task_io_service.ipp:384 0x7ffff773cfef  
    boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run() at task_io_service.ipp:153 0x7ffff773cfef   
    run() at io_service.ipp:59 0x7ffff773914c   
    Wt::WIOService::run() at WIOService.C:180 0x7ffff773914c    
    0x7ffff6bb8e7a  
    start_thread() at pthread_create.c:312 0x7ffff4da4182   
    clone() at clone.S:111 0x7ffff59d847d
```

By analysing the stack trace, I'm pretty sure this is related with the `done()` method from the `Wt::Http::Client` that is not implemented properly, but can't figure out why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion that the problem is that the Client class instance `requete` is declared as a local variable. Also the call `requete.post(...)` is asynchronous, i.e. it saves a request to an internal queue of `Wt` and finishes immediately without waiting till the message is delivered. Thus the `Communication::sendData` method finishes before the `Wt` internal code processes the queue. When `Wt` processes the queue the instance `requete` is already destroyed. Due to this fact the code inside of `Wt::Http::Client::Impl::startTimer()` cannot get a pointer and throws the exception.

Comment: If I change the `requete` variable as a static one, should it be ok?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie, I don't know how the Wt will behave in case of a static variable. [An example of the documentation](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1Http_1_1Client.html) works with an allocated object via a pointer.

Comment: That was my second choice, I'll try them both later today or tomorrow, but I'm pretty sure you put the finger on the right thing, give you news soon!

Comment: Tested with a pointer variable as in the example, so far it is working, than youk putting me on the right track!